# Z3: Is a custom theory extension appropriate for my application?

Tags: z3

I have precise and validated descriptions of the behaviors of many X86 instructions in terms amenable to encoding in `QF_ABV` and solving directly with the standard solver (using no special solving strategies).  I wrote an SMT-LIB script whose interface matches my ultimate goal perfectly:

- `X86State`, a record sort describing x86 machine state (registers and flags as bitvectors, and memory as an array).
- `X86Instr`, a record sort describing x86 instructions (enumerated mnemonics, operands as an ML-like discriminated union describing registers, memory expressions, etc.)
- A function `x86-translate` taking an `X86State` and an `X86Instr`, and returning a new `X86State`.  It decodes the `X86Instr` and produces a new `X86State` in terms of the symbolic effects of the given `X86Instr` on the input `X86State`.

It's great for prototyping:  the user can write x86 easily and directly.  After simplifying a formula built using the library, all functions and extraneous data types are eliminated, leaving a `QF_ABV` expression.  I hoped that users could simply `(set-logic QF_ABV)` and `#include` my script (alas, neither the SMT-LIB standard nor Z3 support `#include`).

Unfortunately, by defining functions and types, the script requires theories such as uninterpreted functions, thus requiring a logic other than `QF_ABV` (or even `QF_AUFBV` due to the types).  My experience with SMT solvers dictates that the lowest acceptable logic should be specified for best solving time.  Also, it is unclear whether I can reuse my SMT-LIB script in a programmatic context (e.g. OCaml, Python, C) as I desire.  Finally, the script is a bit verbose given the lack of higher-order functions, and my lack of access to `par` leading to code duplication.

Thus, despite having accomplished my technical goals, I think that SMT-LIB might be the wrong approach.  Is there a more natural avenue for interacting with Z3 to implement my x86 instruction description / `QF_ABV` translation scheme?  Is the SMT-LIB script re-usable at all in these avenues?  For example, you can build "custom OCaml top-levels", i.e. interpreters with scripts "burned into them".  Something like that could be nice.  Or do I have to re-implement the functionality in another language, in a program that interacts with Z3 via a theory extension (C DLL)?  What's the best option here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think that people write .smt2 files by hand.  These are usually generated automatically by some program.
I find the Z3 Python interface quite nice, so I guess you could give it a try. But you can always write a simple .smt2 dumper from any language.

BTW, do you plan releasing the specification you wrote for X86?  I would be really interested!